# Overlay network with GRE without spanning tree

Tags: spanning-tree, gre, openflow

I need to create an overlay network with potential of hundreds of servers (each is an hypervisor and running a open vswitch).

I'm going to use ovswitch and connect each server to all other servers using GRE. Now as I understand connecting all servers and configure spanning tree can be expensive. So my plan is to not use spanning tree, because I already know all the virtual machines running (and their IP, MAC and switch port) I'm going to fill the flow table of each switch will all the possible routes using Openflow or OVSDB (so any not local MAC address will be route to the correct GRE port).

The question is, is there a downside for this approach? (performance issue?) the flow table is going to be populated with all possible routes, is this too expensive? what other downside can be?

Comment: You are building a private cloud with potentially hundreds of physical servers each running a hypervisor.  What does the physical topology look like?  A pair of data centers?  What type of WAN?

Comment: Spanning tree has its limitations and faults, but I would never describe it as "expensive.  Perhaps you are misunderstanding how it might affect you.  Can you provide more details about your underlay network?

Comment: Using your listed limitations, Is VXLAN possible with the software you have? Otherwise doing spanning-tree (or some of its replacements) is your only option.

Comment: topology is some datacenters and cloud providers (aws and azure), to be exact each server will run containers I want to create overlay network for all containers.

Comment: VXLAN is a problem because multicast is not supported.

Comment: as I understand spanning tree won't be able to handle 100 vswitches all connected to each other.